# SQL query with Highest value with tie

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that lists students who have earned the highest total credit in each department. I have to also include tied students in the result. 
The query should return relation with department name, student name and total credit they earned.

```
SELECT s.dept_name, s.name, s.max
FROM (SELECT dept_name, name, MAX(tot_cred) as max 
      FROM university.student GROUP BY dept_name) as s,
     university.student as t
WHERE s.name = t.name;
```

It is giving errors and I don't know how to deal with ties.
If I delete the name part in the query, I have managed to get the highest credits in each department(without a tie)

The table student consists of an ID, name, department, total credit.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT t.dept_name, t.name, t.tot_cred
FROM (
  SELECT dept_name, name, tot_cred, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY dept_name ORDER BY tot_cred DESC) rn
  FROM university.student 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

This is an alternative in case you can't use window functions:

```
SELECT s.dept_name, s.name, s.tot_cred
FROM university.student s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT dept_name, MAX(tot_cred) tot_cred
  FROM university.student
  GROUP BY dept_name
) t ON t.dept_name = s.dept_name AND s.tot_cred = t.tot_cred
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.dept_name, s.name, s.tot_cred 
FROM university.student s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM university.student
  WHERE dept_name = s.dept_name AND tot_cred > s.tot_cred  
)
```

Comment: It is giving syntax error... Is it available in MySQL?

Comment: It is available in MySql 8.0+

Comment: My version is 8.0.18 but it is giving syntax error... :(

Comment: The query as it is, is syntactically correct. Check the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36dWp2tpZaDszvZu19txjd/0 So I don't know how you use it. Post the full error message.

Comment: 00:52:23 SELECT t.dept_name, t.name, t.tot_cred FROM (   SELECT dept_name, name, tot_cred,      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY dept_name ORDER BY tot_cred DESC) AS rn   FROM university.student  ) AS t WHERE t.rn = 1 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY dept_name ORDER BY tot_cred DESC) AS rn   FROM university.student ' at line 4 0.0016 sec

Comment: Run `select version()` to check the version of MySql.

Comment: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: So you don't have MySql 8.0. I will post another query.

Comment: Thank you so much! you are awesome